# why do i need to draw an Ellipse

Tags: c#, drawing

```
 private void DrawIt()
        {
            System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
                50, 100, 150, 150);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
            graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
        }
```

code from MSDN. why do i need to draw an Ellipse before a rectangle? and how does it work?

Comment: You don´t have to do that, this code simply draws a black ellipse and above this a red rectangle. Omit one and see what happens.

Comment: Where do you want to draw your rectangle into? A existing Image or into a new white scratch?

Comment: Simple: don't draw ellipse if you don't need it. It's a *sample* code, to demonstrate you one of possibilities. Other possibilities (e.g. without drawing ellipse) exist too. Sample code are often used to *run and see what happens*. Do it.

Comment: You can draw just a rectange if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read the code! See it :

1. Draw a ellipse in the point 50, 100 in the size 150 150
2. Now draw  rectangle in the the same point, same size.

   If you use the .FillEllipse and .FillRectangle you will see better the difference , is just like a canvas: If you paint the rectangle, so ellipse, the ellipse will overlap the rectangle.
   In this case you can notice that looking to the intersection of lines, execute the code with the ellipse first, and latter with the rectangle first.